# Problem(s) with Scilab and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, opengl, scilab

I try to use Scilab 6.0.1 (standard repos version) under Xubuntu 18.04.4 (with Ubuntu studio packages). There seems to be a problem (or a combination of problems). First, this bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/scilab/+bug/1807602

seems to be still around with my installation. When starting scilab in the terminal, I first get these errors:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.scilab.modules.jvm.LibraryPath (file:/usr/share/scilab/modules/jvm/jar/org.scilab.modules.jvm.jar) to field java.lang.ClassLoader.sys_paths
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.scilab.modules.jvm.LibraryPath
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Nevertheless, scilab first seems to start all right. Then, as soon, as I start using any graphics output of scilab, a stream of errors appears:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught GLException: Profile GL3bc is not available on X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0.0, unitID 0, handle 0x7fc501d48bf0, owner true, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x43d64870, isOwner true, <3cb97caa, 6c4d7c0e>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <AWT-EventQueue-0>]]], but: [GLProfile[GLES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GL4ES3/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES2/GL3.hw], GLProfile[GL3/GL3.hw], GLProfile[GLES3/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL3/GL3.hw], GLProfile[GL2GL3/GL3.hw]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.initialize(GLJPanel.java:1795)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.initializeBackendImpl(GLJPanel.java:1377)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.paintComponent(GLJPanel.java:549)
```

and so forth. The behaviour of the program is identical if started in a terminal or as a starter directly into the GUI. The result is always that everything looks normal until I start graphing things (can be reproduced by starting one of the graph demos).

It looks like this are 2 different problems. The illegal reflective operation is already documented for this version of scilab and is said to be solved. This fits with the fact that scilab does start. But, the graphics thing seems to be new. Couldn't really find something on it.

Does anyone have an idea on this? Many thanks in advance.

Herdi

Answer (score 0):

Something very similar is happening with Scilab 6.1.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 as well!

However, in my case, Scilab does not start at all!

Really need to get Scilab up and working ASAP!

Here's my log:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.scilab.modules.jvm.LibraryPath (file:/usr/share/scilab/modules/jvm/jar/org.scilab.modules.jvm.jar) to field java.lang.ClassLoader.sys_paths
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.scilab.modules.jvm.LibraryPath
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Could not access to the Main Scilab Class:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.scilab.modules.localization.Messages.gettext(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.modules.commons.xml.XConfiguration.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.modules.core.Scilab.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2646)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
    at org.scilab.modules.localization.MessagesJNI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more

Scilab cannot create Scilab Java Main-Class (we have not been able to find the main Scilab class. Check if the Scilab and thirdparty packages are available).
```

Would be really great if someone could help resolve this!